# well formated code inside the HTML code tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to display some well formatted HTML on my page. That HTML will be compiled in the script. To show that HTML I am using `< pre ><code> HTML CONTENT </code>< /pre >`

The problem is I have no Idea how to add line breaks and other formatting to the variable that is compiling the HTML.

**MY SCRIPT:**

```
var CodeShow = '<div id="builder" class="' + LoginClasses + '">
                <form id="LoginForm" class="formContainer' + FormClasses + '">
                </form></div>';
$('#CodeShow').text(CodeShow);
```

**Expected HTML Result:**

```
 <code>
    <div id="builder" class="classA">
          <form id="LoginForm" class="formContainer classB"></form>
    </div>
 </code>
```

This is a sample HTML however the real HTML has number of lines.

Comment: I think you need to use \n in your variable

Comment: Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/9zz9dy5L/

Comment: @The_Death_Raw your code works but the output is going too wide since there are number of classes assigned to few elements. even used `white-space: pre-line` on the `<code>` but didn't work :(  

Also, please reply as an answer so that I am mark it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var LoginClasses = " classA", FormClasses = " classB";
var CodeShow = '<div id="builder" class="' + LoginClasses + '"> \n <form id="LoginForm" class="formContainer' + FormClasses + '"> \n </form> \n </div>';
$(function() {
  $('#Code').html(CodeShow);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="#CodeShow"><code id="#Code"></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I saw you using .text() I assumed you want to display the result on your webpage. Not just to take effect in your browser. Anyway to display this on the webpage.

var LoginClasses = " classA", FormClasses = " classB";

```
var CodeShow = `&lt;div id="builder" class= "${LoginClasses}"&gt;
   &lt;form id = "LoginForm" class ="formContainer ${FormClasses}"&gt;

   &lt;/form&gt;
&lt/div&gt`;

$(function(){
    $('#CodeShow code').html(CodeShow);
})
```